# Are all biconditionals implications?

Tags: logic, prime-numbers, propositional-calculus

I am currently self-studying propositional logic from the 4th Edition of Mathematical Proofs: A Transition to Advanced Mathematics. Having finished the chapters on negation, implication and biconditionals, I find myself a bit confused, and I believe the best way for me to express that confusion would be from the following example:

Let the following be open sentences, across the domain of natural numbers:

P(x): x is prime.

Q(x): x is equal to 2.

R(x): x is odd.

Now, I’m sure it would be correct to say that:

P(x) and ~Q(x), implies R(x).

However, I’m wondering whether it would be correct to say that:

P(x) and ~R(x), implies Q(x).

Can this even be considered an implication, considering that there is no situation in which P(x) and ~R(x) are false while Q(x) is true? It seems like more of a biconditional, since for one to be true, the other must be true as well, and if one is false, the other one must be false too- however, there’s also no situation in which P(x) and ~R(X) are true while Q(X) is false, so wouldn’t that make the implication valid as well?

**To summarize** my question here, I’m just wondering- can a biconditional be considered implication? If one situation depends on another to be true, and vice versa, does that still mean that one implies the other?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Yes of course. A bi-conditional is the conjunction of two conditionals.

Comment: The way we get $A \iff B$ is by noting $A \implies B$ and $B \implies A$ just as Mauro said. Necessary AND Sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P$ and $Q$ be complex formulas. Then, by definition, a biconditional $P \leftrightarrow Q$ is logically equivalent to $(P \to Q) \wedge (Q \to P)$. In other words, a biconditional is logically equivalent to the conjunction of a conditional $P \to Q$ and its converse $Q \to P$.

Furthermore, if $(P \to Q) \wedge (Q \to P)$ holds, then we can derive either $P \to Q$ or $Q \to P$ on a separate line of proof by *conjunction elimination*, also known as *simplification*. So, given a biconditional like the one above, it is perfectly correct to conclude that $P$ implies $Q$. It is also perfectly correct to conclude that $Q$ implies $P$. That is because the biconditional operator $\leftrightarrow$ implies that both $P$ and $Q$ imply each other.

So as for your example, if we have...

$P(x)$: $x$ is prime.

$Q(x)$: $x$ is equal to $2$.

$R(x)$: $x$ is odd.

then you are correct in saying that, for every natural number $x$...

$( P(x) \wedge \neg R(x) ) \to Q(x)$

You are also correct in saying that, for every natural number $x$...

$Q(x) \to ( P(x) \wedge \neg R(x) )$

So, by definition of biconditional, it is also correct to state that, for every natural number $x$...

$( P(x) \wedge \neg R(x) ) \leftrightarrow Q(x)$

If the first two expressions hold, then so does the third. And if the third expression holds, then so do the first two.